# How to fix stable Debian with hundreds of vulnerabilities

Tags: debian

I'm new to Linux administration, despite being a bsd/linux user for 25 years. I've always been told that Linux is secure and Windows is full of vulnerabilities and now that I've got a Debian 9.13 host to watch over, I ran `debsecan | wc -l` and it reported 384 vulnerabilities (known CVEs based on the packages I've got installed). That was after `apt-get upgrade` with the apt security repo enabled, so all existing security upgrades are already applied, to my understanding.

Does this mean these 384 vulnerabilities just don't have a fix yet or is there another way, besides `apt-get upgrade`, to get the bugfixes?

Comment: Care to mention one (or a few) of those vulnerabilities and the related package in your question?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Here are some examples: https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2018-1000001 , https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2020-25659

Comment: As you can see from the comments on those trackers, the issues have been deemed minor and possibly risky to fix in Debian 9.